# jQueryUI Radio/Check buttons not changing programmatically

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I can predicably read the value of a jQueryUI radio button, however, I am not able to set it programmatically. No matter which methods I use to change the radio button's value, jQueryUI interface will not update its interface.

```
<div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="true" checked="checked" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="false" />No
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#radio').buttonset();

    // One of the many ways that won't work.
    $('[name="radio"]:radio:checked').val("false");
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Once you update the value, like this:

```
$('[name="radio"][value="false"]').attr("checked", true);
```

You need to tell jQuery UI to update, like this:

```
$('#radio').buttonset("refresh");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QzEQZ/).

Comment: the buttonset part of the question wasn't there when I answered. :/

Comment: I would've never thought of this. Thanks.

Comment: @Yanick - It was...he mentioned jQuery UI from the start, that's why my comment posted even before your answer inquires about it :)

Comment: @Nick Crave, I beg to differ. When I answered the question, there was only the HTML part as code (plus the .val() call, that's it). There was no mention of a bottonset. Though I might have expected it, I didn't think the OP was using JQuery UI.

Comment: The original question title has jQuery UI in it, you can see the revisions by clicking the edit link on the question which goes here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3569794/revisions (why do you think I asked about it 2 minutes after the original answer?) :)

Answer (score 8):

i usually do a:

```
$('[name="radio"][value="false"]').attr("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

the buttonset("refresh") call is bound to the change event which is simply not triggered when you're changing the value programatically - triggering it manually solves the ui issue and you don't need to worry about where the buttonset is

Answer (score 4):

```
$('[name="state"]:radio:checked').attr('checked', true);   // checked
$('[name="state"]:radio:checked').removeAttr('checked');   // unchecked
```

** **NOTE** **

```
$(':radio').val();  // same as $(':radio').attr('value');
```

Thus :

```
$(':radio[checked]').val(); // -> the value of the first checked radio button found
```

Comment: I'm thoroughly sorry. I just didn't think there'd be much to such details, given how a regular radio button is pretty straight forward. oO./

Answer (score 2):

i usually do a:

```
$('[name="radio"][value="false"]').prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

Please use "prop" instead of "attr" to change the "checked" state.